# How to configure JBoss 5.1.0GA using JDK1.6 on Eclipse 2018-12 and Fedora 29?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jboss5.x, java-6, jboss-tools

I'm trying to configure JBoss AS Server on Eclipse 2018-12, but I can not create a server Jboss 5.1.0.GA using Jboss Tools 4.9.0.Final. The Error message is:  'This server requires an execution environment from J2SE-1.4 through JavaSE-1.8, but no valid JRE was found. Caution is advised.'

[Error Message - Add Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzAFu.png)

Even Though I have changed the Execution Environment, I can not find a compatible JRE Execution (JDK 1.6) for the Environment Execution.

[Compatible JRE Execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfHHL.png)

Previously I have configured the Installed JRE with a JDK 6.0, but I have noticed that some jars files are not present at moment of config, that are:

- jre/lib/resources.jar;
- jre/lib/jsse.jar;
- jre/lib/jce.jar;
- jre/lib/charsets.jar.

[Libs not present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TCQd.png)

These jars present on oracle jdk_1.6.0_45 are visible at moment of config in the case of Ubuntu 18.04, but on Fedora 29, it is not present.

How can I configure to make possible to add JBoss server, and make it running on JDK1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your configuration on a F29 VM.
Here's what I did:

- installed JDK1.6.0_45 (from Oracle)
- installed 2018-12
- launched 2018-12
- installed JBoss Tools server adapters
- tried to add a JBoss 5.1 but noticed it was not possible
- removed Java 11 (sudo yum remove java-11-openjdk-headless)
- installed Java 8 (sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel)
- relanched 2018-12
- got an error while creating the JBoss 5.1 server
- noticed in the error log JDK1.6.0 is missing the libnsl.so.1)
- installed libnsl (sudo yum install libnsl)
- create and  start server were now successful

Hope this helps